# Xcode 7 doesn't run more: Bad Access

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I was working with Xcode last night, in morning I relaunch the XCode and it crash, an error appears.

I tried to delete the Preferences, cache, reinstall all... nothing.

But if I run Xcode from terminal with root privilege, it runs but Simulator doesn't work properly...

**Error dump:**

> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS) Exception Codes:
>   0x000000000000000a, 0x000000010e8ac000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> VM Regions Near 0x10e8ac000:
>       __LINKEDIT             000000010e83e000-000000010e83f000 [    4K] rw-/rwx SM=NUL 
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator
>   --> mapped file            000000010e83f000-000000010e9e3000 [ 1680K] r--/rwx SM=COW
>       MALLOC_LARGE           000000010e9e3000-000000010ebe9000 [ 2072K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 7B1005
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff99b9852b
>   **CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 795 1   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff99ba844b CFStringCreateWithBytes + 59 2
>
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff99bd4ff9
>   __CFBinaryPlistCreateObjectFiltered + 7273 3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff99bd4c82
>   __CFBinaryPlistCreateObjectFiltered + 6386 4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff99bd4c82
>   __CFBinaryPlistCreateObjectFiltered + 6386 5   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff99bd4c82
>   __CFBinaryPlistCreateObjectFiltered + 6386 6   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff99bd4c82
>   __CFBinaryPlistCreateObjectFiltered + 6386 7   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff99bd4347
>   __CFBinaryPlistCreateObjectFiltered + 4023 8   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff99bd4c82
>   __CFBinaryPlistCreateObjectFiltered + 6386 9   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x00007fff99bb8427
>   __CFTryParseBinaryPlist + 215 10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff99bb7ca9 _CFPropertyListCreateWithData + 89 11 
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff99bb7bad
>   CFPropertyListCreateWithData + 93 12  com.apple.Foundation
>
>     0x00007fff8b8400d7 +[NSPropertyListSerialization
>   propertyListWithData:options:format:error:] + 94 13 
>   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation        0x00000001066a81f3 -[DVTPlugInManager
>   _loadPlugInCache:] + 260 14  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation       0x00000001066a34a5 -[DVTPlugInManager _scanForPlugIns:] + 3304 15 
>   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation        0x00000001073e25e9 IDEInitialize + 3250
>   16  com.apple.dt.IDEKit               0x0000000107adf2fc
>   -[IDEApplicationController applicationWillFinishLaunching:] + 708 17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff99c33c9c
>   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 12 18  com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff99c33c2f
>   ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 63 19  com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff99c33ba7 _CFXRegistrationPost + 407 20 
>   com.apple.CoreFoundation          0x00007fff99c33912
>   ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50 21  com.apple.CoreFoundation         0x00007fff99bf06d2 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar
>   find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1922 22  com.apple.CoreFoundation 
>     0x00007fff99bef925 _CFXNotificationPost + 693 23 
>   com.apple.Foundation              0x00007fff8b82f0fa
>   -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66 24  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation     0x0000000106883d35
>   -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 698 25  com.apple.AppKit               0x00007fff9249d022 -[NSApplication finishLaunching] + 354 26 
>   com.apple.dt.DVTKit               0x0000000106e83494 -[DVTApplication
>   finishLaunching] + 149 27  com.apple.AppKit
>     0x00007fff9249cb65 -[NSApplication run] + 231 28  com.apple.AppKit
>     0x00007fff92465fbe NSApplicationMain + 1176 29  libdyld.dylib
>     0x00007fff8b5eb5ad start + 1

Comment: I noticed that if i run xcode from terminal with sudo, this error appears:
 ### Failed to load Addressbook class CNContactNameFormatter
2015-11-20 13:51:10.787 Xcode[7118:2287139]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///var/root/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%207.1.1.db).

Comment: I had something similar to this, deleting my developer folder and doing a complete reinstall of xcode solved it for me. But i can imagine that might not be an option for you..